# Create separate rooms based on Pin code in the URL in socket io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm new in node js and socket io, I'm trying to create interactive quizzes based on pin code given in the url for ex: `http://domain/start/5555` should create a quiz page with name `5555` and when clients have the pin code they can connect to this quiz. So it means i have to have a quiz page which shows all connected clients for example but i have some prblems with `io.sockets.in(pincode).emit()`
because i don't know if i'm creating rooms correctly or not!
here is my code

**Client.js**

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function () {
    var params = jQuery.deparam(window.location.search);// To get the name and the room

    socket.emit('join', params, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            window.location.href = '/join.html';
        } else {
            console.log('No error');
        }
    });
});
```

**Server.js**

```
app.get('/start/:pincode', (req, res) => {

io.on('connection', (socket) => { // to rigester connection listener
    console.log('New user is connected');

    // When somebody connects it verifies if the name and the room are valid strings
    socket.on('join', (params, callback) => {

        if (!isRealSrting(params.name) || !isRealSrting(params.pincode)) {
            return callback('Name and pincode are required');
        }

        socket.join(params.pincode);
        users.removeUser(socket.id);//Remove the user from other places
        users.addUser(socket.id, params.name, params.pincode);

        var x = users.getUserList(params.pincode);
        console.log(x);

        io.sockets.in(params.pincode).emit('updateUserList', { //here it doesn't work i don't know why!
            users: users.getUserList(params.pincode),
            pincode: params.pincode
        });

        socket.emit('newMessage', {
            user: params.name,
            pincode: params.pincode,
            readyMessage: 'You are connected'
        });// when the user connect to the server he gets this message

        callback();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        var user = users.removeUser(socket.id);

        if (user) {

            io.emit('updateUserList', users.getUserList(user.pincode));
            //io.to(user.room).emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin', `${user.name} has left`));
        }
    });
});
res.render('start.hbs', {
    pincode: req.params.pincode
});
});
```

and the main page
**Start.js**

```
var socket = io();
var pincode;

socket.on('updateUserList', function (users) {
   console.log('here');
   var ol = jQuery('<ol></ol>');
   var usercount = users.users.length; // Players number
   pincode = users.pincode;    
});
```

Any help or suggestion please?

Comment: Result of logging `io.sockets.in(params.pincode)`?

Comment: When i refresh Start.js after the clients connected i get just the console message and an empty array [ ]!

Comment: And `params.pincode` is definitely a string?

Comment: Yeah, it is a string